# How do I modify Windows 98's "SETUP.EXE" file?

Tags: windows, exe

I'm currently trying to make a mod of Windows 98. I successfully modified the autorun.exe file, but now, I'm trying to edit setup.exe, and I've run into some problems.
I first tried it in Resource Hacker, both on Windows 11 and a Windows XP VM, and both came up with the error "This is not a Win32 executable file". I thought "OK, maybe it's a 16-bit program."
So I opened it in Borland Resource Editor, both on Windows 11 and a Windows 95 VM, and they both did nothing. I saw nothing in the center window. What should I do? I would be happy if I could at least
modify the setup background and images.

-TOWF